# A Question Regarding Pinter's Proof for the Following Statement: "Any two cycles of the same length are conjugates of each other"

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, proof-explanation, permutation-cycles

In Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra", Chapter 8 Exercise E2 asks the following:

> Prove that any two cycles of the same length are conjugates of each other.

Pinter puts forth the the *beginning* of the solution:

> "If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are cycles of the same length, where $\alpha = (a_1 ... a_s)$ and $\beta = (b_1 ... b_s)$, let $\pi$ be the following permutation: $\pi (a_i)= b_i$ for $i = 1,...,s$ and $\pi(k) = k$ for $k\neq a_1,...,a_s, b_1,...,b_s$. **Finally, let $\pi$ map distinct elements of $\{b_1,...,b_s\} - \{a_1,...,a_s\}$ to distinct elements of $\{a_1,...,a_s\} - \{b_1,...,b_s\}$**".

The portion that I have bolded is the part that confuses...as I cannot see why this is necessary.

It looks to me like Pinter is specifying a property of $\pi$ that accounts for possible overlap in the two different cycles...so that "*non-overlapped elements*" only map to "*non-overlapped elements*", but I cannot see why this must be done.

From the first two properties of $\pi$, namely:

1. $\pi (a_i)= b_i$ for $i = 1,...,s$

and

2. $\pi(k) = k$ for $k\neq a_1,...,a_s, b_1,...,b_s$

it seems like all relevant features of $\pi$ have been sufficiently described. Why must the last property be included as well?

Comment: If the bolded text is not included, $\pi$ may map 2 elements to the same place, in which case it will not be a permutation.

Comment: how can that be? $a_i$ --> $b_i$ already ensures that this cannot happen, right? Within a cycle, there are no repeated elements. Therefore, doesn't $a_i$ --> $b_i$ already guarantee that it is injective?

Comment: Beta would have to include a repeated element for this to be the case...but if it contains a repeated element, then it is not a cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relevant features of $\pi$ have yet to be defined:   one hasn't yet said what $\pi$ does to elements of $\{b_1,\dots, b_s\}-\{a_1,\dots, a_s\}$.

Furthermore, the elements of $\{a_1,\dots, a_s\}-\{b_1,\dots, b_s\}$ haven't been "hit", or mapped to yet.

Thus the extra condition.

Comment: ahhhhhh, I see. So really the set of all k's $+$ the set of all $a_i$'s $+$ the set of all  " $\{b_1, ..., b_s\} - \{a_1, ..., a_s\}$" covers the whole domain that pi is defined on...

And, correspondingly, the set of all k's $+$ the set of all $b_i$'s $+$ the set of all " $\{a_1, ..., a_s\} - \{b_1, ..., b_s\}$" covers the whole range that pi is defined on. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.   That is correct.